# A way to set AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autoresetevent

I am writing a unit test for some code that another developer wrote.  At one point the developer used a bool statement for WaitOne().  He set up the defaults to be false, is there way to set WaitOne() to be true for the unit test?  From what I have read about WaitOne it has to do with threads and I am just trying to write a simple unit test first to make sure what was written works?  Does anyone know of a way in the unit test I can set WaitOne to true?
I looked at the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477.aspx.  It mentioned that when it receives a signal it will be true.  Can and how would I use the unit test to send the signal

Comment: Look into the docs to see when it will return true.

Comment: I already looked into the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477.aspx.  It returns true when it receives a signal.  How would I create that signal

Comment: You're right, they don't say.

Comment: I hope my answer helps you a little more :)

Answer (score 0):

The docs are vague about this issue. `WaitOne` returns true if it returns due to the `WaitHandle` being signaled as opposed to being in a timeout situation.

I have confirmed this with Reflector. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx and method `InternalWaitOne`.

Comment: Non-Reflector source: [InternalWaitOne](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/waithandle.cs#e5e509644abd4e5d)

Comment: So it looks like .set() allows other threads to go while waiting and .WaitOne returns true if those threads are done before the allotted time.  So there is not way to unit test this without using testing for multi threading.

Comment: Yes. You probably should find another way to test. Maybe just write a simple wrapper around an event that is two events: The normal event and one that you can signal at any time in a testing context. Use `WaitHandle.WaitAny` to combine the two.